# How to save subversion password with bzr-svn

Tags: passwords, bazaar, bzr-svn, bazaar-plugins

I am using bzr-svn to chekout  svn repositories using bazaar. But bzr-svn asks for passwords everytime, I searched the web to find out about authentication.conf

I put the following section authentication.conf

```
[something]
scheme=svn+http      #tried http only or svn only
host=uuuuuu.com
path=/svn/project    #tried without stating path
user=wwwww 
password='mmmmmm'    #tried without quotes
```

In all cases either I was prompted for password, or got the following error

```
bzr: ERROR: Permission denied: ".": OPTIONS of 'http://xxxxxxxxx/': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://gamernetwork.unfuddle.com)
```

I put the same snippet in bazaar.conf and subversion.conf, but I got the same results/errors.

How can I use bzr-svn without typing my password each and every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned from #bzr IRC channel that bzr-svn can use cached authentication info of regular subversion client.

You just have to checkout the project once with svn, saving the user name and password. After that, bzr svn can use this password.